# Relation of screen size and browser size

Tags: css

I am wondering if there is any relation between screen size and browser window width and height. Will screen of 13" will have always the same browser max width and height (in pixels)? Or is it possible to have for example 11" screen with 1900x1000 size?

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no relationship directly between screen size in inches and screen pixel density as measured in pixels.

To answer your two questions clearly:

1. A screen of 13" will NOT always have the same browser max width and height (in pixels)
2. Yes it IS possible to have for example [an] 11" screen with 1900x1000 size. (Since there is no relationship between screen size and pixels this could occur, along with any other combination)

Max browser size, is by definition, (minus browser chrome I suppose to be pedantic) equivalent to the maximum pixel resolution of the monitor, and the pixel resolution of the monitor is not related to its physical size.

Of course there are averages. There are common occurrences of relationship between monitors and pixel width and height, but they are not rules.

One could guess that most monitors are 16:9 and have pixel densities of say 92dpi, and then given the inches width you could calculate the pixel width, but those things are not absolutes.

Comment: Great - except that is not what was asked. Go back and read the question.

Comment: I think it IS what you asked haha, but I'll edit my answer to be clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your resolution depends on the PPI (pixels per inch). The higher the density of the display, the higher the PPI.

The typical relationship for wide screen displays is 16:9 - but remember that displays are measured from corner to kitty corner of the screen. You would never have a 1900 x 1000 screen on a standard 16:9 display. It would be more like 1440 x 900 in order to maintain the 16:9 ratio.

Comment: So there is a relation between browser size and screen resolution - is that correct?

Comment: As per my answer below, no there is not. Bigger screens would likely have more pixels on them, but remember that an iPhone has more pixels than you large TV screen. There is no relationship between physical size and pixel density, and hence no relation between physical size and the amount of pixels on the screen (resolution). Feel free to mark my answer correct - since it is ;)

Comment: Actually, you are dead wrong. Perhaps reading the posters question next time will result in you not giving bad answers.

He did not ask about the relationship between the physical size and the PPI.

Comment: Yes and No OP. There is not a direct relationship, but there is a relationship. 

A common misconception is that higher pixel density means things will render smaller. This is not the case. For example, retina displays will render images using 2x the amount of pixels that it would on a standard display. The result is more detail at the same size. 

An inch is an inch - but the amount of pixels used to achieve that inch varies by display. You don't have to worry about this when developing as rendering correct SIZE is handled by the client device.